# javascript property non enumerable still found by for... in

Tags: javascript, enumerable

I'm writing a little javascript library: I've defined an `Item` object, then added a function with `Item.prototype.addNumber` and finally I set it as not enumerable, but if I try to log Item's method using `for...in` loop the function still appears.
This is my code, Am I doing something wrong? (tested on Chrome 18 and Firefox 11)

```
function Item() {
    ...
}

Item.prototype.addString= function() {
    ...
}

Object.defineProperty(Item, "addString", { enumerable: false });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're defining the property on `Item` instead of on `Item.prototype`.

```
Object.defineProperty(Item.prototype, "addString", { enumerable: false });
```

---

If you used `Object.defineProperty` to *initially* add `addString` to `Item.prototype`, then you could explicitly *(or implicitly)* set the property descriptors at the same time...

This will implicitly set `enumerable:false`, as well as `false` for `configurable` and `writable`.

```
Object.defineProperty(Item.prototype, "addString", { 
    value: function() {
        ...
    }
});
```

Or if you wanted only `enumerable` to be `false`, you could do this...

```
Object.defineProperty(Item.prototype, "addString", { 
    value: function() {
        ...
    },
    configurable: true,
    writable: true
//  ,enumerable: false  // uncomment to be explicit, though not necessary
});
```

Comment: but isn't it false by default? look on the quote in my answer. And I didn't see in the MDN article `*.prototype` at all.

Comment: @gdoron: Doing `Item.prototype.addString = func...` is enumerable by default, so `Object.defineProperty` is used to set the enumerable setting. If the `Item.prototype.addString` property had been *initially* created using `defineProperty`, then yes, it would have been non-enumerable.

Comment: ohhh, so can you use this instead: `Object.defineProperty(Item.prototype, "addString", { });` **?**

Comment: @gdoron: Sort of. If you were using it to initially define the value of the property, you'd need to use the `value: func...` of the third argument. I'll give an update.

Comment: @gdoron: Yeah, when I use SO as a resource, I give as much attention to votes as I do to green checks. I think the asker is more influenced by the votes than anyone, so lots of votes can lead to a green check. You're right... it's not perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a property (`addString`) directly on `Object` (the non enumerable one) and another `addString` (enumerable by default) on the `Item`'s prototype.

A `for ( in )` iterates over properties up the prototype chain, that's why it appears there.